# Twitter live search stream

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am looking for a solution that would provide subscription-like responses that would contain results for particular tag from twitter.

I saw plenty of REST/ STREAM scripts for node.js but these scripts connect to twitter just once.

I would like not to be worried about rate limits.

Basically what I want to do is set up a notification (ex. console log) if there is a new search result for 20 different tags.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

With the streaming API you are only supposed to use a single connection, however it can contain multiple keywords (comma delimited) in the `track` attribute, and can be combined with other search parameters such as location and user filters.

The idea is that you use the one stream to collect all the data you need, and then process/filter that data independently to display or store as you please.